# Is IHostedService for start/stop IBus needed in MassTransit V8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit, .net-6.0

I am using MassTransit with RabbitMQ in a ASP.Net Core (.Net 6) microservices project. Now I have upgraded to MassTransit Version **8**. Currently I am using a IHostedService to start and stop the Bus:

```
public class BusService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IBusControl _busCtrl;

    public BusService( IBusControl busCtrl )
    {
        _busCtrl = busCtrl ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( busCtrl ) );
    }

    public Task StartAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
        => _busCtrl.StartAsync( cancellationToken );

    public Task StopAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
        => _busCtrl.StopAsync( cancellationToken );
}
```

Service Registration:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();
```

I read now that "**MassTransit will automatically add an IHostedService for MassTransit**". So does this mean that I don't need such a Service to start/stop the bus anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you no longer need to add your own hosted service. Calling `AddMassTransit` will add all required services and health checks to the service collection.

The above service would be duplicative, and should not be used with MassTransit v8.